# spanish and lost figure

Tags: floats, babel, languages, spanish

I want to use `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` because I am writing a text in Spanish language. Now, when I make that, the figures get lost!, they cannot be read any more. The changes that I expect are done such as having the names, **Figure**, **Table** and **Bibliography** in Spanish. However, the figures disappear. I guess, that have something to do with the way I am given the figure command. I am giving:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{"Graphics/Princp usos F"}
    \caption{Principales usos de los Humedales}
\end{figure}
```

If I use `\usepackage[english]{babel}`, then the language of the floats will be in English again. But in this case the Figures will appear.
I do not know exactly where the problem comes from. Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{grffile}`

Comment: Wow! that was quickly! and it works perfectly, Thanks a lot @egreg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using files with spaces in their names is usually discouraged. Quotes around the name are a partial solution, but when `babel` is loaded along with language modules that define shorthands with `"` it won't work.

The solution is not using files with spaces in their names or, if you can't avoid it, loading also

```
\usepackage{grffile}
```

(after `babel` is best).

Comment: I see, thats new for me, and really important. I will try always to use file names without spaces. Thanks for the explanation @egreg